# JSON Parser in Apex

Tags: apex, json, parser

The image shows my JSON Parser Value. I've attached my apex code below. While I run that code I'm getting the value which I've lined it in black color. But I need to get the value which I've lined in green color. I don't know how to parse that specific value in Apex code. Please, anyone, help me to overcome this problem.

[image]

```
 JSONParser parse3=JSON.createParser(result);   
    while (parse3.nextToken() != null) {
     if ((parse3.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
            (parse3.getText() == 'name')) {

            parse3.nextToken();

           customer.add(parse3.getText());
                System.debug(customer);
        }
    }
```

JSON :

```
    {
  "Invoice": {
    "Deposit": 0,
    "AllowIPNPayment": false,
    "AllowOnlinePayment": false,
    "AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment": false,
    "AllowOnlineACHPayment": false,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "148",
    "SyncToken": "0",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2019-01-09T04:20:02-08:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2019-01-09T04:20:06-08:00"
    },
    "CustomField": [
      {
        "DefinitionId": "1",
        "Name": "Crew #",
        "Type": "StringType",
        "StringValue": "20"
      }
    ],
    "DocNumber": "1041",
    "TxnDate": "2019-01-09",
    "CurrencyRef": {
      "value": "USD",
      "name": "United States Dollar"
    },
    "LinkedTxn": [],
    "Line": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "LineNum": 1,
        "Description": "Installation of landscape design",
        "Amount": 50.0,
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemRef": {
            "value": "7",
            "name": "Installation"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 50,
          "Qty": 1,
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "NON"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 50.0,
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
      }
    ],
    "TxnTaxDetail": {
      "TotalTax": 0
    },
    "CustomerRef": {
      "value": "59",
      "name": "Monica Manickam"
    },
    "CustomerMemo": {
      "value": "Thank you for your business and have a great day!"
    },
    "SalesTermRef": {
      "value": "3"
    },
    "DueDate": "2019-02-08",
    "TotalAmt": 50.0,
    "ApplyTaxAfterDiscount": false,
    "PrintStatus": "NeedToPrint",
    "EmailStatus": "EmailSent",
    "BillEmail": {
      "Address": "gmmonica29@gmail.com"
    },
    "Balance": 50.0,
    "DeliveryInfo": {
      "DeliveryType": "Email",
      "DeliveryTime": "2019-01-09T04:20:06-08:00"
    }
  },
  "time": "2019-01-09T05:49:21.274-08:00"
}
```

Comment: did you try it? It will create the classes for you. I think it very easy...-> http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

Comment: To understand the JSON parsing, this blog post will help you to understand how JSON objects are treated by Salesforce Apex JSONParser. https://scotthung.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/how-to-parse-a-json-response-using-salesforces-jsonparser-class/

Comment: Can you provide me the JSON? I can give you the code.

Comment: Sure @ProlayChaudhury.